# Redis Master/Slave Replication - Permission denied connecting to master

Tags: redis

I'm trying to set up master/slave replication, but the slave cannot seem to connect to the master.  I have two virtual servers set up on Hyper-V running Redis 2.8.19 on CentOS 7.  Both servers were set up using the CentOS Minimal installation.  I performed the initial setup using the guide at Digital Ocean, How to Configure a Redis Cluster on CentOS 7 (I removed the link so I could link my redis.conf files below). All of the settings in redis.conf not mentioned specifically in the tutorial are left as their defaults.

I noticed right away that the master and slave weren't connected when viewing INFO on the slave, so I checked out the redis.log and found this over and over:

```
[3384] 12 Apr 15:06:17.885 * Connecting to MASTER 10.10.0.138:6379
[3384] 12 Apr 15:06:17.885 # Unable to connect to MASTER: Permission denied
```

Which permission is it though?  I assumed that it was a firewall issue.  I double-checked the settings in firewall-cmd and they seem to be correct:

```
[ichibanchef@gldev-redis-slave ~]$ sudo firewall-cmd --list-all
public (default, active)
  interfaces: eth0
  sources:
  services: dhcpv6-client ssh
  ports: 16379/tcp 6379/tcp
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
```

*I opened 16379 when checking to see if maybe that port was necessary for replication like it is for clustering*

I verified that I could do all of the following from each server to the other:

- redis-cli PING
- Connect via redis-cli -h [host] -p [port] -a [password]
- Telnet to host on port 6379

Other stuff I've done:

- Verified that my .NET client, StackExchange.Redis, can connect to both of the servers and read/write data when they're not set up for replication
- Disabled Transparent Huge Pages on both servers
- Set vm.memory_overcommit=1 on both servers
- in SELinux, enabled the following: httpd_can_network_connect, httpd_can_network_connect_db, and httpd_can_network_memcache

I'm not really sure what else to try and I don't know how to tell which permission it is that the slave doesn't have in order to connect to the master.  I'm a complete linux newb, so please keep that in mind when replying.

I don't have enough reputation to post the links to my INFO outputs.  Hopefully I can add them as comments.

[Master redis.conf](https://www.dropbox.com/s/er5hgks8qnozvlt/redis.master.conf?dl=0)

[Slave redis.conf](https://www.dropbox.com/s/555d4kulhnfa9aa/redis.slave.conf?dl=0)

Comment: [Master INFO](https://www.dropbox.com/s/uqm28l89vhimats/redis.master.info?dl=0)

Comment: [Slave INFO](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fnhm1rfsd93sb28/redis.slave.info?dl=0)